# Load image from sdcard to imageview not working

Tags: android, imageview, sd-card

Tried many methods, but did not reach a positive outcome.
In TableLayout has ImageView:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/photo_layout_background"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:background="@color/photo_layoutrow_background"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_photo"
        android:background="@color/photo_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="addPhoto_Click"/>
```

When you click on `ImageView` offer standard procedure for obtaining pictures and the file is saved on the SD card:

```
public void addPhoto_Click(View v){
    select_add_photo_id = v.getId();
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, generateFilePhotoUri());
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_RESULT);
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private Uri generateFilePhotoUri() {
    File file = null;
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    file = new File(MEDIA_PATH + String.valueOf(id) + File.separator + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    select_add_photo_file = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return Uri.fromFile(file);
}
```

The photo is saved normally stored in variables select_add_photo_id id ImageView on which tapped the select_add_photo_file variable holds the full path to the file photo.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(select_add_photo_id);
            imgView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(select_add_photo_file));

        }

    }
}
```

But when the file is only get ImageView ImageView with background and increased size. Photography is not loaded. There are no errors.

As still set photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after take a phone, in onActivityResult, data.getData may be null, in this case, try data.getExtras()

```
Bitmap photo = null;  
Uri photoUri = data.getData();  
String filePath = "";
if (photoUri != null) {  
    //mFilePath = getRealPathFromURI(photoUri);
    filePath = getRealPathFromURI(photoUri);
    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoUri.getPath());  
}  
if (photo == null) {  
    Bundle extra = data.getExtras();  
    if (extra != null) {  
         photo = (Bitmap)extra.get("data");
...
```

Comment: Error on Uri photoUri = data.getData();

Comment: @SmallSani more detail? I used this code in one of my project and it works.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the program logic. Yes, your code works. Thank you!